# Use of definite article before superlative adverbs

Tags: adverbs, articles, definite-articles, superlative-degree

What is the rule regarding the use of definite article (***the***) before superlative adverbs? Is it mandatory, optional, or not required at all to use ***the*** before superlative adverbs?

Comment: As in "Out of all of them, he played it the most prettily" and "Out of all of them, he played it most prettily" or just "He played it most prettily" (which is potentially ambiguous)? Examples illustrating your question and what you take each sentence to mean would help here, I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between like best and like the best?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338175/is-there-any-difference-between-like-best-and-like-the-best) Also [Is there any difference between like best and like the best?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338175/is-there-any-difference-between-like-best-and-like-the-best), [The usage of “the” with “least”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88362/the-usage-of-the-with-least) and probably others.

Comment: Are you asking if *he did it best* is wrong, and if it must be *he did it **the** best* instead? It would be helpful if you provided an example sentence or two.

Comment: Please give some examples!!!!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Those Q's are about two specific adverbs, this is about adverbs in general. In addition *like best* is a weird idiom, where *best* has weird properties, and a weird meaning. Would be better to get a good answer here for adverbs in general (Also more easily searchable for future users). For comparison: *She danced most beautifully* versus *She danced the most beautifully* <--- Not really the same at all as the *best* thing is it?

Comment: @Araucaria: *It really is **the strangest** thing*. That may be a rather dated construction, when used with the exact sense of *It really is **a strange** thing* (or plain *It really is **strange***). But if I allow myself to "settle in" with that usage, I find it easy enough to see your beautiful dancer examples as *precisely equivalent* from that "dated" perspective, even though I can also look at it from a more modern / logical perspective and see a clear semantic distinction.